# Is it possible to return a response and call a function together with it in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to return a response via my API function and it works just fine. However, right now, I'm trying to execute a public function in the same controller whilst also returning a response. Is this possible?

```
return response()->json($success);
```

But what I want is to send the above response together with this;

```
return $this->sendSMS($data);
```

($data) has been predefined already.

Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: So `sendSMS()` produces output too? `return response()->json(array_merge($success, $this->sendSMS($data));`. You can't perform black magic here, it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add it to data?

```
$dataWithResponse = compact('data', 'response');
try {
    $this->sendSMS($dataWithResponse);
} catch(/Exception $e) {
    // Somehow handle exception
    echo $e->getMessage();
    return response()->json($success);
}
return response()->json($success);
```

Comment: the thing im worried about this, is that, if there is something that fails in the sendSMS function, a response wont be given in my main function. but other than that fear/worry, it's actually the best solution there is.

Comment: @UdhayanNair, I modified my code to show you a basic aproach to handle exceptions. But better take a look on https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php If this answer was useful just accept it

Comment: hey, i think with the exception, it works just fine. I should have thought about that. But yeah, it works well now! thanks mate :)